# Combining data from 2 tables?

Tags: mysql

I've been duplicating my data as as noted by the asterisk `*` below in **Snippet 1**.  This duplication allowed me to run a simple query as such:

```
"SELECT * FROM tweets ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 7",
```

This populates 7 tweets as a default setting.

However, I want to eliminate these redundant columns.  To do this I need to pull the other fields from the credentials table.

How would I run a complex query like this?  Is this feasible?  Is it a good idea?

**Snippet 1**

```
Table 1 - tweets (7)

id
h_token
h_file    *remove and pull from credentials
picture   *remove and pull from credentials    
name      *remove and pull from credentials
tweet
time 



Table 2 -  credentials (12)


id
name
email
h_pass
picture
privacy
h_token
h_file
special
page
pane
remember
```

Each tweet has an h_token associated with it that will be used to add relational data (h_file, name, and picture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a join operation, like so:

```
SELECT tweets.*, credentials.h_file, credentials.picture, credentials.name 
    FROM tweets JOIN credentials ON tweets.h_token=credentials.h_token 
    ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 7;
```

This is basically your original query, but adding three columns from the credentials table whenever the h_token from the credential and tweets table match up......

Comment: Definitely. That's the advantage or a relational database.

This way if you update a row in credentials, you don't have to update some large number or rows in tweets.